# Batch File To Copy Text File To FTP Site

Tags: ftp, copy, batch-file

I have a text file on one computer that I want to send to a folder on a ftp site.
Can someone please show me a batch file code that will login to the FTP site with the username and password, and copy the text file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about from a Windows environment. So for arguments sake, let's say the text file is C:\textfile.txt and I need to copy it to the FTP site in the folder called BACKUPS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean batch as in Windows batch, you can do that with the following script `tst.cmd`:

```
@ftp -n -stst.ftp myTargetMachine.com
```

(replacing `myTargetMachine.com` with the name of your actual FTP server) and the following FTP command file `tst.ftp`:

```
user myUser myPassword
dir
bye
```

Obviously, you should replace the `myUser` and `myPassword` with your actual username and password, and also `dir` command with whatever you really want to do, such as:

```
put localfile.txt /fullpath/remotefile.txt
```

---

If you're talking about a UNIX-like environment, the script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp -n myTargetMachine.com <<EOF
    user myUser myPassword
    dir
    bye
EOF
```

Same deal with the FTP server name, user ID and password, of course.

---

And, in response to your comment:

> Yes, I am talking about from a Windows environment. So for arguments sake, let's say the text file is C:\textfile.txt and I need to copy it to the FTP site in the folder called BACKUPS.

You would use a script like the following `transfer.cmd`:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
c:
cd \
ftp -n -stransfer.ftp myTargetMachine.com
endlocal
```

and `transfer.ftp`:

```
user myUser myPassword
put textfile.txt /backups/textfile.txt
bye
```

---

If you wanted the Windows version as a single file, you could use something like:

```
@echo off
echo user myUser myPassword>tst.ftp
echo dir>>tst.ftp
echo bye>>tst.ftp
ftp -n -s:tst.ftp myTargetMachine.com
del /q tst.ftp
```

which temporarily creates `tst.ftp` and then deletes it when it's finished.

Comment: So they are 2 seperate files on the Windows computer. One called 'transfer.cmd' and the other called 'transfer.ftp'?

Comment: Yes, while Linux provides an easy way with `here-docs` (see the `EOF` stuff in that script), that's not so easy with Windows. If you _really_ just wanted one script, you could make the `x.ftp` one from `x.cmd` temporarily: see the update.

Comment: You can output multiple lines at once by placing multiple `echo` calls into a block of parentheses. Couldn't you just pipe those to `ftp` without the need of a temporary file? On a single line (comments) it might be: `(echo user myUser myPassword&echo dir&echo bye)|ftp ...`

Answer (score 1):

Command:

```
ftp -n -sScriptName HostName
```

And in the Script:

```
   [User_id]
   [ftp_password]
   ascii
   put myfilehere.html /remotedir/remotename.txt
   quit
```